# Upper bound for $u_n(z) = n^{-2}\sec (\pi z / 2n)$

Tags: analysis

I've been working through past exam papers for an Analysis exam that's coming up. This question has had me tearing my hair out, and I would appreciate some help:

Use the Weierstrass M-test to prove that:

$f(z) = \displaystyle \sum^\infty_{n=1}u_n(z)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{Z}$, where $u_n(z) = n^{-2}\sec(\pi z / 2n)$.

Hint: $|\cos z | \geq |\cos (\mathrm{Re} z)|$

---

I understand how the M-test works, I need to find bounds $M_n > |u_n(z)|$ such that $\sum M_n$ converges. Then the sum converges uniformly, so $f$ is continuous. The difficulty in the question is that $u_n(z)$ is unbounded on the domain (which can be restricted to $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Z}$ using the hint).

In order to use the M-test, I need to find a 'trick', and I just can't see it. I've considered things like:

- grouping terms together so that they 'cancel', and become bounded. For example, $|\cos(x)| + |\cos(2x)|$ is bounded below.
- trying to convert this into a geometric series via exponentials, which works for series like $\sum \cos(k\theta)$

Is it very simple, and I'm just not seeing it? This question (which has other, semi-related parts that I had no problem with) is supposedly designed to be accomplishable in around 40 minutes for studious candidates, and I have spent many times that on it.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can find $M_n$ that works for all $z$, since $u_n$ is unbounded. You need to find a cover for your domain, $U_1,U_2,\dots,$ And for each $U_i$ show uniform convergence. Essentially, you want $U_i$ to be strictly bounded away from the integers.

Comment: Of course, you're right! Attempting to prove that $f$ is uniformly convergent on the whole domain is stronger than necessary to deduce that $f$ is continuous (and probably not even true?), I see that now. Well, I'm embarrassed that the answer was so simple. Could somebody please advise me what I should do with my question (submit my own answer, delete, or something else?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: When you can't prove uniform convergence on the entire domain, try showing it instead for each element in an open cover of that domain. So pick $U_1,U_2,\dots$ that cover your domain and for which you can prove uniform convergence on each $U_i$.

Comment: Thank you for this swift, clear answer to what turned out to be a rather dull question.